# Night Mode with Rasperry Pi Zero Camera Module

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspivid

I'm trying to take some pictures with the Raspberry Pi Zero and the optional camera module in pitch-black. I am wondering what the best options are to use when invoking `raspivid`. I have tried:

```
raspivid -o pixel-${DATE}.${EXT}
         --ISO 500
         --profile high
         --exposure night
         --exposure fireworks
         --nopreview
         -t 10000
```

Other options such `shutter` (which I believe requires me to use `--codec MJPEG`) and tweaking ISO don't seem to help. Unfortunately all I get is a dark image.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? What options do I need to use to take pictures in the dark? Or does it require additional hardware?